# How can I attach a MixPanel event to when the user clicks a Facebook Like button?

Tags: jquery, facebook-like, mixpanel

I'm using the latest Facebook "Like" button widget, and would like to track a MixPanel event when a user clicks "Like".

I looked at the DOM using element inspector and derived the following JQuery event:

```
$(".pluginConnectButton div div button").click(function(event) {
  mixpanel.track("Facebook like");
});
```

...but it does not trigger.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/

Comment: Awesome, thanks! This was the code I ended up using: 

 `$(document).ready(function() {
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
   FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
       function(response) {
     if (response == 'https://www.facebook.com/MY-FAN-PAGE')
            mixpanel.track("Facebook like");
       }
   );
  }
 });`

Comment: @CBroe, feel free to add answer and I'll vote you up.